# Instantiating an inner class when outer class declared as a var in Scala

Tags: scala

When I am declaring my outer class object as a `var`, I am not able to instantiate the inner class. But when I am making it as a `val`, I am not getting any error. Why is this happening?

```
class Outer(name : String ) { ter  =>
  class Iner(name : Inner) {
    println("Printing outer class name : " + ter.name )
    println("Printing inner class name : " + name )
  }
}

object OverRiding extends App {
  var outr : Outer = new Outer("Priyaranjan Outer")
  var inner =  new outr.Iner("Priyaranjan Inner")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in a constructor invocation, the expression referring to the class getting instantiated must be a stable identifier. That is required in the language specification at http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#constructor-invocations

If you look at the definition of a [stable identifier](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#paths), you will see why `outr` has to be a `val`:

> - p.x where p is a path and x is a stable member of p. Stable members are packages or members introduced by object definitions or by *value definitions* of non-volatile types.

Comment: though you'd get away with typing it with a path independent type, but apparently not. til

Comment: Not according to the spec, I'm afraid.